# mysql generate EMI pay date list

Tags: mysql

**If my current_date ='2020-01-17' and Emi=5
generate dates like**

1)2020-02-17

2)2020-03-17

3)2020-04-17

4)2020-05-17

5)2020-06-17

**current_date ='2020-01-30' and Emi=3
generate dates like**

1)2020-02-28

2)2020-03-30

3)2020-04-30

**current_date = '2020-01-31' and emi=3
generate dates like**

1)2020-02-28

2)2020-03-31

3)2020-04-30

**could you please anybody help me to generate the date then insert to the table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure generate_EMI_pay_date_list(start_date date, records_count int)
with recursive
cte as (select 1 num
        union all
        select num+1
        from cte
        where num < records_count)
select start_date + interval num month
from cte;
```

```
call generate_EMI_pay_date_list(current_date, 5);
call generate_EMI_pay_date_list('2020-01-30', 3);
call generate_EMI_pay_date_list('2020-01-31', 3);
```

---

> but my server MySQL version is 5.6.51 – Murugan
>
> @Murugan What is maximal possible value for your `Emi` parameter (max. amount of rows to be generated)? – Akina
>
> max 48 rows.... – Murugan

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_EMI_pay_date_list(start_date DATE, records_count INT)
SELECT start_date + INTERVAL num1.num * 7 + num2.num MONTH
FROM (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION 
      SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) num1
JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION 
      SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7) num2
WHERE num1.num * 7 + num2.num <= records_count;
```

Comment: How to insert the value?

Comment: @M.S.Murugan ?? Insert what? insert where? if you have one more question - create one more topic.

Comment: insert the EMI date values to the MySQL table column.

Comment: @M.S.Murugan Use `INSERT INTO` instead of `SELECT` in main query. Or `UPDATE`, but in such case you must to form some value in CTE which allows to link each generated date and a record which must be updated with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969236/mysql-insert-value-stored-with-some-gap

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969236/mysql-insert-value-stored-with-some-gap

Comment: @Akina. it is not working in MySQL  5.6.51

Comment: @Murugan Of course, recursive CTE is supported in 8+ version only.

Comment: but my server MySQL version is 5.6.51

Comment: @Murugan You should specify this from the same beginning in the question text. What is maximal possible value for your `Emi` parameter (max. amount of rows to be generated)?

Comment: max 48 rows....

Comment: @Murugan The variant applicable in your version added.

Comment: it is working. but the date is not in sequence

Comment: @Murugan *but the date is not in sequence* I don't understand this phrase. Does some intermediate values are lost?

Comment: is this logic work for a maximum of 1000 rows? (What is the maximal possible value for your Emi parameter)

Comment: @Murugan *is this logic work for a maximum of 1000 rows?* You may expand `numX` subqueries or/and increase their amount and use according number generation expression. This allows to produce as many numbers/rows as you need. *What is the maximal possible value for your Emi parameter* In theory there is no limit. But there are limits by memory usage, disk usage and so on - the attempt to generate numbers till, for example, 1kkk may easily hang the server.

Comment: can you please update the query for 120EMI? I have tried to expand the numX but the result is duplicate. please help me. @Akina

Comment: Expand `num1` up to 11 and `num2` up to 10. Replace multiplier from 7 to 10.

Comment: @Akina. I have tried. but still, have an error. can you please update the answer for 120 EMI

Comment: @Akina. please help me

Comment: @Akina. Please help